# Laravel 4.2 Custom Pagination Button - Adding a ID with each button for AJAX call

Tags: php, mysql, css, ajax, laravel-4

I am using [this](http://www.stillat.com/blog/2014/07/21/creating-a-custom-pagination-view-in-laravel/) tutorial for creating a custom pagination in Laravel 4.2.

I am getting this code-

```
<ul class="pagination">
        <li class="disabled">
            <span>«</span>
        </li>
        <li class="active">
            <span>1</span>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="http://localhost/car/public/specials?page=2">2</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="http://localhost/car/public/specials?page=2" rel="next">»</a>
        </li>
</ul>
```

for pagination buttons.

But I need to add some AJAX and some JS call with ID's.

So, I want this kind of code for this buttons-

```
<ul class="pagination">
        <li class="disabled" id="prev">
            <span>«</span>
        </li>
        <li class="active" id="page[1]">
            <span>1</span>
        </li>
        <li id="page[2]">
            2
        </li>
        <li  id="next">
            <span>»</span>
        </li>
</ul>
```

Is it possible?

Please help me.

Thanks in advance for helping.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i will give a simpler approach....

put this in anywhere in *views* folder. let's say you put it (and named it) as *partials/pagination.blade.php*

put the following code in *pagination.blade.php* (*modify it to match your view*)

```
@if ($paginator->getLastPage() > 1)

    <ul class="pagination">
    <li><a href="{{ $paginator->getUrl(1) }}" id="page[1]" class="{{($paginator->getCurrentPage() == 1) ? ' disabled' : '' }}">Previous</a></li>
    @for ($i = 1; $i <= $paginator->getLastPage(); $i++)
    <li><a href="{{ $paginator->getUrl($i) }}" id="page[{{$i}}]" class="{{($paginator->getCurrentPage() == $i) ? ' active' : '' }}">{{ $i }}</a></li>
    @endfor
    <li><a href="{{ $paginator->getUrl($paginator->getCurrentPage()+1) }}" id="page[{{$paginator->getCurrentPage()+1}}]" class="{{($paginator->getCurrentPage() == $paginator->getLastPage()) ? ' disabled' : '' }}">Next</a></li>
    </ul>

@endif
```

**Note: above code is a sample. change the layout to suit your need.**

i prefer `a tags` while writing links.

while calling the paginator, use the following,

```
{{$paginator->links('partials.pagination')}}
```

No need to go through all those complicated process.

**but** more of a chance is, whatever you are trying to do, can be done purely with javascript.

Answer (score 0):

You can extend the `lluminate\Pagination\Presenter` class and implement its abstract methods. For example (Put it in `app/extension` folder):

```
class CustomPresenter extends Illuminate\Pagination\Presenter {

    public function getActivePageWrapper($text)
    {
        $url = $this->paginator->getUrl($this->paginator->getCurrentPage());
        $query = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_QUERY);
        parse_str($query, $params);

        return '<li id="page['.$params['page'].']" class="active"><a href="">'.$text.'</a></li>';
    }

    public function getDisabledTextWrapper($text)
    {
        return '<li class="disabled"><a href="">'.$text.'</a></li>';
    }

    public function getPageLinkWrapper($url, $page, $rel = null)
    {
        $query = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_QUERY);
        parse_str($query, $params);
        $id = $params['page'];
        return '<li id="page['.$id.']"><a href="'.$url.'">'.$page.'</a></li>';
    }
}
```

Add an entry in `composer > autoload > classmap` section like this:

```
//...
"app/tests/TestCase.php",
"app/extensions"
```

To use the Custom Presenter:

At first, create a `view` (`custom-presenter.php`) in `app/views` directory. Then, replace pagination option in the `app/config/view.php` configuration file with the new view's name, like this:

```
'pagination' => 'custom-presenter'
```

Finally, the following code would be placed in your custom presenter view:

```
<ul class="pagination">
    <?php echo with(new CustomPresenter($paginator))->render(); ?>
</ul>
```

For `prev` and `next` use this `JavaScript` (I've used `jQuery`) and include this in you template:

```
<script>
    $(function(){
        $('ul.my-custom-pagination>li:first').attr('id', 'prev')
        $('ul.my-custom-pagination>li:last').attr('id', 'next')
    });
</script>
```

Above `JS` code will set the `id=prev` and `id=next`, otherwise there will be duplicate ids for first two `li`s and last two `li`s. At last, run `composer dump` from terminal. This an output of this implementation:

```
<ul class="pagination my-custom-pagination">
    <li id="prev"><a href="http://taj.dev/ladger/agency/index?page=2">«</a></li>
      <li id="page[1]"><a href="http://taj.dev/ladger/agency/index?page=1">1</a></li>
      <li id="page[2]"><a href="http://taj.dev/ladger/agency/index?page=2">2</a></li>
      <li id="page[3]" class="active">
          <a href="">3</a></li><li class="disabled" id="next"><a href="">»</a>
     </li>
</ul>
```

[Read more on the manual.](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/pagination)